# tcolorbox not working as intended

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox

I'm trying to create a tcolorbox for an example environment, but it behaves differently depending on the size of the text written. For example, I'd like it to look like this when there is no text:
[image]

But with my code it looks like this:

[image]

When  there is text it behaves sometimes as intended:

[image]

And this is the way it should be:

[image]

But when there is little text does not work properly[image]

This is the code of the box:

```
\newtcolorbox{example}[1]{parbox=false, blanker, enhanced, breakable,
before skip = 5mm, after skip = 5mm, left=3mm, right=3mm, top=10mm, bottom=3mm,
colback=white, colframe=cor1, width=162mm, toprule=1pt, 
bottomrule=1pt, rightrule=1pt, leftrule=1pt, outer arc = 8mm, arc = 8mm, 
sharp corners = northwest, sharp corners = southeast, sharp corners = southwest,
title={{\boxfont EXEMPLO}\hspace{3.5mm} 
\textcolor{gray!80!black}{\Large\extitlefont\makefirstuc{#1}}}, 
boxed title style={empty, sharp corners}, 
attach boxed title to top left={xshift=-1.3 mm , yshift=-10mm},
underlay boxed title ={
% Draw the title underlay rectangle
\fill[cor1!30] ($(frame.north west) + (0,-.5mm)$) rectangle ($(title.north east)+(-.8mm,-8.5mm)$) coordinate (R);
%)
%;
% Filldraw the darker fancy in front of the rectangle and behind the Example. The coordinates should be better chosen.
\fill[cor1] (frame.north west) -- ($(title.south west) + (1.3mm,0)$) -- ++ (18mm,0mm) arc [start angle=-90, end angle=0, x radius = 2mm, y radius = 2mm] -- ($(frame.north west) + (20mm,0)$) --  cycle;


}
}
```

If anyone could help me I'd be really grateful.

Comment: Welcome to TeX. SE. What is your complete code? Can you edit, please, your question, if possible? Surely we are here to help you. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, my complete code ir very big, because it's a book, but it'be helpful to show only the preamble and an example of the box being used?

Comment: Sorry for my delay. If you could just take out a part of the book, as happens to me, someone might be able to help you. Otherwise, your question will be closed in the future. Thank you and good work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `\ifstrempty` to differentiate the title depending on if there is a title text or not.

Since you did not provide a complete MWE, I invented the command `\boxfont` and `\extitlefont` and the color `cor1`.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand{\boxfont}{\normalfont}%<---invented
\newcommand{\extitlefont}{\bfseries}%<---invented
\colorlet{cor1}{cyan!70!green}%<---invented
\newtcolorbox{example}[1]{
    parbox=false, 
    blanker, 
    enhanced, 
    breakable,
    before skip = 5mm, 
    after skip = 5mm, 
    left=3mm, 
    right=3mm, 
    top=10mm, 
    bottom=3mm,
    colback=white, 
    colframe=cor1, 
    width=162mm, 
    toprule=1pt, 
    bottomrule=1pt, 
    rightrule=1pt, 
    leftrule=1pt, 
    outer arc = 8mm, 
    arc = 8mm, 
    sharp corners = northwest, 
    sharp corners = southeast, 
    sharp corners = southwest,
    title={{\boxfont EXEMPLO}%
        \ifstrempty{#1}{\ignorespaces}{%
            \hspace{3.5mm}%
            \textcolor{gray!80!black}{\Large\extitlefont\makefirstuc{#1}}}}, 
    boxed title style={empty, sharp corners}, 
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift=-1.3 mm , yshift=-7mm},
        underlay boxed title ={
            \ifstrempty{#1}{%
                \fill[cor1] (frame.north west) -- ($(title.south west) + (1.3mm,0)$) -- ++ (20mm,0mm) arc [start angle=-90, end angle=0, x radius = 2mm, y radius = 2mm] -- ($(frame.north west) + (22mm,0)$) --  cycle;%
                }{%
                % Draw the title underlay rectangle
                \fill[cor1!30] ([yshift=-.9pt]frame.north west) rectangle ($(title.north east)+(-.8mm,-6.77mm)$) coordinate (R);
                % Filldraw the darker fancy in front of the rectangle and behind the Example. The coordinates should be better chosen.
                \fill[cor1] (frame.north west) -- ($(title.south west) + (1.3mm,0)$) -- ++ (20mm,0mm) arc [start angle=-90, end angle=0, x radius = 2mm, y radius = 2mm] -- ($(frame.north west) + (22mm,0)$) --  cycle;
            }
        }
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{example}{}{}
An example without title.
\end{example}
\begin{example}{The title}{}
An example with title.
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

[image]